# a generic lock-free synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, compare-and-swap

The implementation of lock-free data structures is sometimes not easy to implement. The following approach may seem generic and easy but I think here we have some issues:

```
private AtomicBoolean lock = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void func(...) {
        while !lock.compareAndSet(false,true);
        // Some code goes here...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        lock.set(false); 
    }
}
```

I think The code above is not really "lock-free", as it locks the awaiting Threads in the while loop in busy-wait mode.

Therefore, the code is suitable only when the "right" lock-free synchronization is impossible.

My question is - Is it possible to implement a generic lock-free with some different approach and it will works so threads will not be in blocked(like synchronized) or busy mode state and the code will run parallel, so we improve performance?

My aim is to keep the threads running. I know that if the code is long, it is better to use the synchronized mechanism instead of the lock-free implementation, so let's assume we are talking on short code.

For example, below is example of Linkedlist which I think is good approach but it not generic for common data stractures. 
if we are used here with AtomicBoolean as I show above, it will not be realy "lock-free".

```
public class LinkedList<T> {

    private AtomicReference<Link<T>> head = new AtomicReference(null);

    public  void add(T data) {
      Link<T> localHead;
      Link<T> newHead = new Link<>(null, data);

      do {
        localHead = head.get();
        newHead.next = localHead;        
      } while (!head.compareAndSet(localHead, newHead));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"a generic lock-free"*?

Comment: @kaya3 I have updated my post with another approach for linkedList which seems a good one, but if we using the AtomicBoolean approach here in linkedList, we will again in busy-wait.

Comment: Are you looking for a fully general way to take a piece of code, put `Atomic` in a few places and have the resulting code be lock-free?

Comment: @kaya3 exactly!

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed universal construction schemes for lock-free or even wait-free algorithms. For example:

- [A Methodology for Implementing Highly Concurrent Data Structures](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221643573_A_Methodology_for_Implementing_Highly_Concurrent_Data_Structures)
- [A highly-efficient wait-free universal construction](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221257088_A_highly-efficient_wait-free_universal_construction)
- [A Wait-Free Universal Construct for Large Objects](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.01676)

However, these are usually more interesting from a theoretical perspective rather than a practical one. In practice, specialized lock-free algorithms usually perform better than those derived from these universal constructions.

If you are interesting in the area of lock-free programming I would recommend to start with the book [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123973376).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Putting down 4 different links ... doesn't make up a real answer ...

Comment: @GhostCat salutes Monica C. what exactly are you missing? The question was whether there exists a generic way to make an algorithm lock-free. I did answer the question (yes, there is), and for more information, I referred to the most important and most recent publications I am aware of. I certainly wouldn't want to copy&paste the content of these articles, so I am not sure what additional information I should have included.

Comment: The problem is that "yes there is" on its own ... how much value does that give to your future readers? The point of answers that link elsewhere is ... in the end, your answer should still "work" when the links are all broken. Ask yourself: if all links above are broken, how much value would be in your answer?

Comment: I get your point, but even if the links are broken, the title of publications should be enough to find it on your own using our favorite search engine. I could add additional information like the original authors to make the search easier. But in general this topic is to broad and to complex to include all details in a simple post, so I still prefer to reference external sources.

Comment: Yep, one could argue that the question itself is already a bad fit for this place ...